# Oder By Date In post Meta

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wp_query to get post but i want it's order by date saved in my post meta

I try it using meta_key and order_by but it's not working

```
 $args = array(
 'post_type'  => 'obituary',
 'posts_per_page' => 10,
 'paged'          => $paged,
  'meta_key' => 'user_date_of_death',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
 'order' => 'ASC',

 );
 $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

and date saved format in post meta is 06/28/2016

Answer (score 0):

Use below argument in the post query.

```
$today_date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+2 hours'));
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'obituary',
               'order'     => 'ASC',
               'meta_key'  => 'user_date_of_death',
               'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
               'meta_query' => array(
                                  array(
                                    'key' => 'user_date_of_death',
                                    'value' => $today_date ,
                                    'compare' => '>=',
                                    'type' => 'DATE'
                                    )
                                 )
              );
```